# Silverlight RIA query failing using authentication & impersonation

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, authentication, ria, impersonation

Database: Sql Server 2005
Webserver: IIS 5.0
IDE: Visual Studio 2010

I've created a Silverlight RIA application which will allow users of our intranet query one of our databases. 
In the config I have set the authentication to windows and enabled impersonation.
In IIS i have disabled anonymous access and only enabled windows authentication.

This all works fine in my development environment and when running it from VS2010.
When i publish it to my local web server and connect to it from my local pc it works too.

However if i access the URL to the application on my local web server from another machine the application does not work. It gives the following error: "Load operation failed '[QueryName]'. Exception type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException' was thrown.

The database sits on its own server. However i have the same database locally and if i change the connectionstring to local at the local version of that database it works fine.

IIS on my PC does not seem to forward requests to the SQL Server machine. As im running profiler to see what requests come in.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Im sure im missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was an issue was a classic double hop problem when using windows authentication. instead i used annoymous access on IIS and set the App Pool to an account that had access to the database on SQL Server